# Magento 2 include template with form in CMS Block

Tags: magento2, template, cms-block

I have been struggling trying to put a template functionally working inside a CMS Block.
When I put this code inside my CMS block the template is correctly implemented

```
{{block class="Experius\DonationProduct\Block\Donation\ListProduct" name="cms.donation.list" template="Experius_DonationProduct::donation.phtml"}}
```

However, the template has a **pop up window** that comes up when you click a button, and that pop up has a form.
The problem is that the pop-up window does not come up when it's in the CMS block, it's like if JS functions were not working.

The template is located in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Experius_DonationProduct/templates/donation.phtml`
its override from the original module.
What can I do?
Thank you and greetings!

Comment: Can you include examples?

Comment: What kind of example?

Comment: The js and some markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see a problem with cms block associated with the method `\Experius\DonationProduct\Block\Donation\ListProduct::getIdentifier`.
The problem is that when we get the block name in cms, we get a name that contains an element "\" that can not be properly processed. Please try change method getIdentifier for that

```
return str_replace('\\', '-', parent::getNameInLayout());
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain where should I put that code line?

Comment: It works now, but in the checkout now it sends me this message : {"success":"You added Donation to your shopping cart."} and does not redirects to checkout, the thing is that this module uses the same template for different areas. The same template is in Checkout, Home page and side bar of product catalog page. Do you know if it would work if I create a separated template for the checkout? Greetings!

Comment: As i see in the code there are only methods that overload the page (only the one on which they are now) after adding to the product in the basket, to add a redirect from all the places you need to make changes to the code.
1. in method \Experius\DonationProduct\Block\Donation\ListProduct::getProductCollection
need add this code $this->setAjaxRefreshOnSuccess(true);

Comment: Also need will add correct (correct it mean what you need) redirect to method /Experius/DonationProduct/view/frontend/web/js/view/donation.js::InitAjaxCart after success function.
for example window.location.replace(url.build('checkout/));  instead location.reload(); on donation.js

Comment: And change my preview fix 
return str_replace('\\', '-', parent::getNameInLayout()); 
to
return str_replace(['\\', '.'], '-', parent::getNameInLayout())

Comment: I really appreciate it, str_replace(['\\', '.'], '-', parent::getNameInLayout()) did the trick , now I will try to figure how to have 2 templates different, one for Homepage and one for checkout.

Comment: Create new template for example checkout_donation.phtml and set it in method \Experius\DonationProduct\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::getDonationForm
$donationProductsBlock->setTemplate('checkout_donation.phtml');

Comment: Hello , should I write again that method? or I can separate it with comas like  $donationProductsBlock->setTemplate('donation.phtml', 'checkout_donation.phtml');